# jQuery: Loop through 20 different IDs for "Select" Dropdowns to Execute Function on Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, html-select

I currently have 20 different SELECT and OPTION HTML dropdowns, I need the same function to happen on all of them when a "change" occurs. I know the wrong way to do this is to repeat the function 20 times, there has to be a way to loop through the ID selectors and execute when a change occurs.

The example below isn't the live example, so the reason I'm doing it this way doesn't matter (ie.  I need to grab both the value and the text within the option to pass through to my final function upon selection change) as much as, How do I loop through the IDs without repeating the same function 20 times.

For the sake of this example, valLit & langLit are variables that each drop down can change, but only one at a time, and passes through to another function.

jQuery to Loop:

```
$('#mySelect0').change(function(event) {
valLit = $('#mySelect0').val();
langLit = $('#mySelect0 option:selected').text();

//Function to Execute on Change Event Goes Here (Same Function for All)

});

$('#mySelect1').change(function(event) {
valLit = $('#mySelect1').val();
langLit = $('#mySelect1 option:selected').text();

//Function to Execute on Change Event Goes Here (Same Function for All)

});

$('#mySelect2').change(function(event) {
valLit = $('#mySelect2').val();
langLit = $('#mySelect2 option:selected').text();

//Function to Execute on Change Event Goes Here (Same Function for All)

});
```

And so on and so forth for 20 times...

Here is the HTML select drop downs for the sake of the example:

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
<select id="mySelect0">
<option value="">Choose Social Network</option>
<option value="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
<option value="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</option>
<option value="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect1">
<option value="">Choose News Source</option>
<option value="https://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="https://www.foxnews.com">Fox News</option>
<option value="https://www.abcnews.com">ABC News</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect2">
<option value="">Choose Shopping Source</option>
<option value="https://www.amazon.com">Amazon</option>
<option value="https://www.walmart.com">Walmart</option>
<option value="https://www.bestbuy.com">Best Buy</option>
</select>
```

And so on for 20 selector drop downs...

I have 20 drop downs on the same page, so I had to create my change event function 20 times for it to work, declaring each select ID in each function, duplicating alot of the same code.

Wondering how to make one function for all that loops sthrough all 20 select IDs

Comment: use a common class instead of ids to select the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily transform this into a loop. However, you don't even need a loop to do it with jQuery, if we assume that only these elements will have ids beginning with `mySelect`.

```
$('select[id^="mySelect"]').change(function(event) {
    valLit = $(this).val();
    langLit = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    //Function to Execute on Change Event Goes Here (Same Function for All)

});
```

(EDIT: as @ArunPJohny says, this would be cleaner/easier to use a class rather than a bunch of separate IDs.)

Comment: Thanks! this was very informative, I need to learn more about jquery it looks like, I didn't realize there was a function like this.

Comment: No problem! And to be clear, this doesn't rely on any special "function" within jQuery - it's just that if you have a jQuery object representing several elements, you can attach event listeners to all of them at once, and within the handler, `this` refers to whichever element is the event target.